# Internal Server Error with Microsoft.XMLHTTP code converted to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, webclient

I've inherited some VB6 code that uploads some data to a website.  I'm trying to convert it to C#.  I initially tried using `WebRequest` object, but doing some more research, I tried a `WebClient`.  Both seem to have problems.

Here is the code that I've inherited:

```
' The object that will make the call to the WS
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

' Tell the name of the subroutine that will handle the response
'oXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = HandleStateChange
' Initializes the request (the last parameter, False in this case, tells if the call is asynchronous or not
oXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://path.to.webpage/Update.asmx/UpdatePage", False
' This is the content type that is expected by the WS using the HTTP POST protocol
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

'Now we send the request to the WS
oXMLHTTP.send "userName=user&password=password&html=" & ThisMessage
```

`ThisMessage` is actually a string that has dynamically created html.

This is the c# translation of the vb6 code:

```
public static void PostHTML(string uri)
    {
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        request.Credentials = credential;

        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string postString = GetWebTemplate();
        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        var response = request.UploadString(uri,"POST", postString);

        Debug.WriteLine(response);
        request.Dispose();
    }
```

This is pure "test" code.  the uri is `"https://path.to.webpage/Update.asmx/UpdatePage"`, and although the `postString` is different from the `thisMessage`, it is a valid html page.
I've tried `request.UploadString()` and `request.UploadData()` (using the byteArray that has been commented out).  I've also tried changing the encoding.

The problem I get is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I'm not sure why I'm getting the Internal Server Error, as the VB6 code is still happily running without error!

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm going to suggest two things: one is that you seem to be sending the credentials differently in the two examples.  In the VB example it is sending it as part of the form data, the C# is sending it in the headers. If you want the C# code to mimic the VB code then you need to send data the same way.  Second suggestion is that you get some sort of network monitoring software or debugging proxy (Fiddler, Charles, etc) and use this to compare the actual HTTP requests.  This will give you a far better idea what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, third suggestion is that if possible you check logs on the server to see exactly what caused the 500 error. I think it's because you're not sending form data when it's expecting it, in the format `userName=X&password=Y&html=Z`.  You're just sending `Z`

Comment: that solved it!  Thanks.  I might have discussions with the web host re modifying what they've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from @pcdev, this is the final code that works:

```
    public static void PostHTML(string uri)
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postString = "userName=user&password=password&html=" + GetWebTemplate();
        var response = request.UploadString(uri,"POST", postString);
        Debug.WriteLine(response);
        request.Dispose();
    }
```